# 4-digit password with unique digits not in ascending or descending order

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I need to calculate how many possible passwords there are if each password is 4 digits long, using the digits 0-9. All digits in the password must be unique, and cannot all be neither increasing nor decreasing. For example “3569” is not allowed, because the digits are in increasing order, while “1374” is allowed

I know that a four digit password could be anything between 0000 to 9999, hence there are 10,000 combinations. But I am now stuck figuring out how to calculate the number of all possible passwords that are unique, neither increasing nor decreasing. 
I have tried to calculate the possible number of passwords if every digit only may be used once:
$$P(n,r)=\frac{10!}{(10−4)!}=\frac{10⋅9⋅8⋅7⋅6⋅5⋅4⋅3⋅2⋅1}{6⋅5⋅4⋅3⋅2⋅1}=5040$$
But I am now quite sure if this is the answer to the question? If not how should I calculate such a question?

Comment: Is your username an hash() or just random nonsense that is meant to look like an hash()

Comment: @RomanGräf 120 bit hashes are not very common, unless it is truncated. SE usernames have room enough for a 128 bit hash though.

Comment: @RomanGräf **Update** I assumed that two characters at the end were missing, so I ran all the 256 possibilities through a dictionary reverser for various 128 bit hash functions. c1a5298f939e87e8f962a5edfc206918 is the md5 hash for 'Hi'.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As you have already worked out, there are $^{10}P_4=5040$ passwords that repeat no digit.

From this number we are to subtract those passwords whose digits are all increasing or all decreasing. All such passwords can be generated by picking four digits out of the ten *without regards to order* – there are $\binom{10}4=210$ ways to do so – and then arranging them in increasing or decreasing order as required. Since we have two choices of order, we subtract $210\cdot2=420$ passwords.

Hence there are $5040-420=4620$ passwords with unique digits that are not all increasing or all decreasing.

Comment: Now if the adversary knows you do this you've made their job easier.

Answer (score 22):

There are $\binom{10}4$ ways to select $4$ distinct digits.

Under the condition that there is no increasing and no decreasing they can be arranged in $4!-2$ ways.

So that gives a total of:$$\binom{10}4\left(4!-2\right)$$ possibilities.

Comment: I've written a small Python script for verification and I hereby confirm that indeed there are 4620 possibilities.

Comment: @Dominique Thanks. I would rather say that it is confirmed now that Python and your script are okay :-).

Comment: @drhab: Or at least that any bugs happen to cancel each other out. :-)